# I think I've got .htaccess issue

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and a LAMP stack. I'm having strange issues with my Joomla site and I suspect that maybe it's because of my errors in running a web server. Since it's not a Joomla forum, I won't get into Joomla problems too deep, but in short -- I'm getting a wrong addresses when I create new menu items (A strange directory "Feeds" appears and I see just the main Joomla page)

If I recall correctly, when I created my original Joomla site in J 1.5 I did use .htaccess in my Joomla root and I chose an appropriate option in Joomla admin panel. Another important point is that I built an original site in a hosting environment (ie, on a distant server, probably running PHP 5.3 I would assume). I'm not an expert in Apache, but I think that I must use a certain directive to enable use of .htaccess (I think it's disabled by default). I haven't enabled it. The reason why I even decided to upgrade my Joomla installation from J 1.5 to 2.5 is because I had issues when I tried to add a payment module in Virtuemart and I thought that maybe the reason was because of incompatibility of J 1.5 and PHP 5.5 (it's a default PHP version under Ubuntu 14.04). And though I did successfully an upgrade of Joomla version from 1.5 to 2.5, after that I couldn't open any of my menu items (except for the home page). I was getting 404 errors everywhere! And then I turned off my "Use URL rewriting" option and renamed back .htaccess to htaccess.txt And after that everything got back to normal (everything that was already there, not NEW menu items -- I simply didn't create any new menu items at THAT point in time).

What I'm trying to ask here... Maybe I should just enable .htaccess use in Apache to avoid those kind of issues? And what's the right way to achieve that under Ubuntu 14.04 and LAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was a Joomla/Virtuemart issue, not really a web server problem. Had to go to Menu manager in Joomla and press Rebuild button there to get menu items in order.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as valid ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know joomla, but most of CMS are using .htaccess to do URL rewriting.

- So 1st step :

Add the following code in your /etc/apache2/site-enabled/{yoursite}.conf
to try to enable .htaccess to see if it solve your trouble

```
<Directory /path/to/joomla/www/root/>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to check that /path/to/joomla/www/root/.htaccess exist

- 2nd Step

If it worked, you can get rid of this by copying .htaccess content into your /etc/apache2/site-enabled/{yoursite}.conf virtual host configuration.
Then you can remove the step 1 and the .htaccess it should now work without !

Comment: The problem is solved. It was a Joomla/Virtuemart issue, not really a web server problem. Had to go to Menu manager in Joomla and press Rebuild button there to get menu items in order.